# PHP - How to remove text and format form a echo string?

Tags: php, string

I have a string called `$file_path;` for a php gallery, When I make `<?php echo $file_path; ?>` **"gallery/png.png"**, **"gallery/jpg.jpg"**, **"gallery/gif.gif"** etc, for all img files on that directory. I want to remove **"gallery/"** and **".format"** for the `$file_path;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo basename($file_path,".png");
```

[basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) will return only the file name

really a third version of the question, next time work out what you want to ask first please:

```
echo pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

this will echo "file" if `$file_path` is "gallery/file.jpg"

Comment: edited answer, dont keep changeling the question please @Kake

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope it will work.

```
$file_path = str_replace('gallery/', '', str_replace('.png', '', $file_path) );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
str_replace('gallery/', '', $file_path);
```

Comment: @Kake you can use str_replace('.png', '', $file_path);

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "gallery/test.png";
$string = str_split($url);
$phase = 0;
$output;
for($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i++){
if($phase==1){if($string[$i]!="."){$output.=$string[$i];}else{break;}}else{if($string[$i]=="/"){$phase++;}}}

echo $output;
```

Only outputs filename